# Top navigation issue on iPhone Devices AMP

Tags: html, ios, amp-html

My client is using an iPhone 6 Plus, and is reporting that the AMP top navigation is going off the screen to the right on her device.

[image: Top Navigation going off to the right on iPhone]

The URL for the site is https://springfieldcc.net/amp/.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue doesn't seem to be an AMP issue.
If you remove padding and margin from *.CTA* / *.CTAheader* class, it should work.

[image]